# Centralized python location on server

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am facing issue to run python scripts in our project. project is a kind of code commit automation task in between we do patch build test and like like that several other processes and that requires a lot of server machines on different geolocation, for example, lets say in Banglore we have around 40 linux ubuntu based server machine and in Sunnyvale we have around 30 and in another location we have around 20 other server machines.

now in these, server we have one centralized location and dis space allocated around
500 gb for our project. `/volume/myproject`  where we keep our project files.

i wanted to know what will be the best way to run the python from the one centralized location so i don't have to install the dependencies on each and every server. right now i am struggling with this as we have python and its dependencies install in each and every server.

point to be noted here is each server has it's on os which is Ubuntu Linux but some server space `/volume/myproject` sync to each other.

i tried to create a virtual environment in a centralized location but it does not resolve the issue though i am able to access the env on each server.

any suggestion is really appreciated here.

Comment: I'd suggest using a configuration management tool like ansible to do the installs. Running from a centralized location just feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. are you saying that using this configuration tool we can install the all the dependencies in all servers.

Comment: also we are already using Jenkins

Comment: Correct. Jenkins is not a configuration management tool; ansible, salt, chef, puppet are what you need. Depending on how the VMs are provisioned, and how often the dependencies change would dictate the method I would use. You could definitely run a jenkins job to run the provisioning.